# Statistics probability Math question: If you draw 3 cards from the deck what is the probability that all the cards would all be different?

Tags: probability

In a deck of $52$ cards there are $4$ suits; hearts and diamonds which are red and spades and clubs which are black. There are thirteen cards in each suit. If you draw $3$ cards from the deck and place all $3$ face up on the table one at a time, what is the probability that all the cards would all be different suits?

Can someone please guide me on what next steps to take ?

I figured since they have to be all different the denominators should decrease by one since we aren't replacing so I calculated ...

$$\frac{13}{52} \cdot \frac{13}{51} \cdot \frac{13}{50} = .25 \cdot .2549 \cdot .26= .7649$$

Comment: You seem to have added instead of multiplying. (Though the answer would be wrong if you multiplied, too.)

Comment: A good way to think of this is from a combinatorial point of view: For the first card, theres 52 ways to choose a card from a 52-card deck. Now for the second card there is 52-13=39 ways to choose a card that does not have the same suit as the first card. Continue this for the 3rd. Then to get the probabilities you divide by the number of ways to choose a card of any suit at each step, giving you 52,51,50 respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The chance that the first card is of some suit is 1 (100%). The chance that the second card is of a different suit is 39/51. The chance that the third card is of a different suit from the first two is 26/50.

So overall the answer is 1 * (39/51)*(26/50). (Thanks to the two commenters for pointing out a mistake in the original answer.)

Comment: Err.. of course, you are both right. I'll fix.